# Removing brackets from fully qualified table name using Toad

Tags: toad

I've just recently installed Toad and I'm trying to change the settings around because one thing I like doing is adding square brackets around the fully qualified table names since it's easier to look at for me, but when I type a fully qualified name, Toad auto-completes it and removes the brackets, eg:

```
[DB].[schema].[table]
```

becomes:

```
DB.schema.table
```

So, is there a way around the auto complete feature removing these brackets? I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to agree with Toad.  Break that habit and save yourself some typing  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately when you have large scripts and many connections, having brackets around the connections helps with finding things. Otherwise it's just words jumbled together and is hard to read.